# Wix: How to enable multiple or single installation using the same installer?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, instance-transform

Is it possible to enable to choose whether we can have multiple or single installation using the same installer (but different build)? Maybe using command prompt or any other method? Currently if I set the Product Id, it will only allow single instance installation. For testing purpose, we want a workaround to allow multiple instance installation. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: The explanation of the problem is not clear to me. Do you have one Wix project and two configurations (Debug and Release) and you want to have them both installed in Program Files, but in different paths?

Comment: Check [**I want to install an MSI twice**](http://serverfault.com/questions/54386/i-want-to-install-an-msi-twice) to see if it is along the lines of what you want to do. I list several options in my answer a bit down the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the MSI file, the documented way to do this is use the MSINEWINSTANCE property set to 1, together with a transform that changes the ProductCode. Both need specifying on the command line. You can generate that transform by opening the MSI file with Orca and using Transform=>New Transform and then changing the ProductCode in the property table and saving the transform mst file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370326(v=vs.85).aspx